# WATCH ing TOP command - ANSI color code suppression

Tags: raspbian-buster

I'm running Raspian buster.

I want to `WATCH` the `TOP` command.  When I do so, I get what I believe are ANSI color/formatting codes.  The codes don't appear when TOP is run from the command line -- instead, the codes cause enhanced display like black on white text.

```
^[?1h^=^[?25l^[H^[2J^(B^[mtop - 13:02:21 up  2:55,  1 user,  load average: 0.13, 0.09, 0.09^(B^[m^[39;49m^(B^[m^[39;49m^[K
```

If I use the --color parameter on the WATCH command, things are way better.

```
1h=25l(Btop - 13:02:51 up  2:56,  1 user,  load average: 0.08, 0.08, 0.08(B(B
Tasks:(B  83 (Btotal,(B   1 (Brunning,(B  82 (Bsleeping,(B   0 (Bstopped,(B   0 (Bzombie(B(B
%Cpu(s):(B 14.3 (Bus,(B 14.3 (Bsy,(B  0.0 (Bni,(B 71.
```

But there still a lot of extra characters.

Anybody know how to get TOP to display the same way under `WATCH` as it does from the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

top already auto updates in increments, which is the purpose of the watch command, what are you trying to do with using both? If you want colors you can use htop or nmon?